# How to solve TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am new to Python and trying to solve the following.
I have an excel sheet with phone-numbers in different formats.
I would like to change them to only one format. **+31612345678**

These are the formats I see in the sheet:

[image: telephone-#]

Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

telephonesheet = 'telefoon-nummers.xlsx'

df_telephonesheet = pd.read_excel(telephonesheet)
df_telephonesheet['fixed_mobile'] = (df_telephonesheet['number']
                        .str.replace('\s+', '', regex=True) # remove unwanted characters
                        .str.extract('^(?P<prefix>\+31)?0?(?P<number>\d)?[-.\s]?(?P<numbers>\d+)') # extract prefix/number
                        .fillna({'prefix': '+31'}) # replace prefix
                        .apply(''.join, axis=1)    # join to form number
                        #.apply({'number': lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str))})
                    )
print(df_telephonesheet['fixed_mobile'])
```

When I remove the special characters in the excel sheet it'll format it like this and run:

[image]

With the special character in the Excel sheet it'll print **TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found**

Comment: Try replacing `df_telephonesheet['number']` with `df_telephonesheet['number'].astype(str)`

Comment: `df_telephonesheet['fixed_mobile'] = (df_telephonesheet['number'].astype(str)`


Still displays: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: is always +316 the country code for that dataframe?

Comment: +31 is the country code. The 6 is start of a mobile number.
The international format for country-code + mobile number always is +316 - rest of number

Comment: Can you provide another numbers like phone examples or another examples that your dataframe contains? Not sure if you dataframe contains line numbers or numbers from other countrys. I ask this because it may be easier to generate another regex to extract the information

Comment: +31 is the only country code that I have in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your '+' pattern in the regular expression is not optional and you didn't specified patterns for '(', ')', and '-'(after 31).
Do like this.

```
...
        .str.extract('^(?:\(?(?P<plus>\+)?(?P<prefix>31)\)?-?)?0?(?P<number>\d)?-?(?P<numbers>\d+)')
        .fillna({'plus': '+', 'prefix': '31'})
...
```

But I don't recommend such a verbose and inflexible code for a string conversion. Use a plain conversion function like this.

```
import re
...
def fix(s):
    s = re.sub('[^\d]+', '', s)
    s = '+' + ('31' if len(s) == 10 else '') + s
    return s[:3] + s[4:]
df_telephonesheet['fixed_mobile'] = df_telephonesheet['number'].apply(fix)
```

Comment: That worked! What I get now is the format +310612345678
How do I remove the zero between +31 and 6? 
So that it becomes +31612345678

Comment: Then just do an another slicing, like ```s = s[:3] + s[4:]```. But my conversion code was just an example. You are better to remove characters except digits and '-' first, split with '-', left justify fields with zeros, truncate fields, give default values for missing fields, and finally join the fields.